# Highlight selected ListView item

Tags: java, android, listview, highlight

Okay so I've been able to hightlight an item in a ListView, but it ends up highlighting every fourth item. I'm pretty sure that's because of recycling. Then I had the issue where the highlighted item would go back to normal after I scrolled, and that's also because of recycling. Is there any way to keep it highlighted, or to maybe stop the ListView from recycling?

This is what the code looks like right now...

```
runTimes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {     
                v.setSelected(true);

        }
    });
```

This is the code where the highlighted item goes back to normal after you scroll.

Comment: is it possible for you to have a `highlighted` variable in wherever your data for the ListView comes from? And then in your adapter you can highlight if the variable is true? That would help with the recycling problems

Answer (score 2):

to hilight a row you should not touch the view at all. you should use listviews [setItemChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int,%20boolean)) with a selector as the background of your view.

```
runTimes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {     
                runTimes.setItemChecked(pos,true);

        }
    });
```

you also need to make sure you keep track of the last position you selected so that you can deselect it when you select a new one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop `ListView` from recycling you should think again if you really need a `ListView`.

To properly accomplish this with a `ListView`, though, you need to save the highlighted item states inside of your adapter. Then in `getView` highlight the items based on their position.

There have been A LOT of questions about saving the state of the `ListView` items, I'm sure you can find some.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding another question that helped me figure out how to do it. This is what I did. In the OnClickListener I check to see if something has been pressed before. If it hasn't been pressed before, then I set the views background color, and prevRunView to the view. If something has been pressed before, then I change the previous view background color to white. After that I do the same thing as before, but for the different view.

```
if(runIndex == -1){
                runIndex = pos;
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6A6A8"));
                prevRunView = v;
            }else{
                prevRunView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                runIndex = pos;
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6A6A8"));
                prevRunView = v;
            }
```

In my adapter I wrote this code so it won't seem like it's recycling.

```
if(ScoreActivity.runIndex == position)
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6A6A8"));
    else
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```